# Why can't I pull up the taskbar when Chrome is maximized?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Whenever I maximize Chrome in Windows 8 the auto-hide on my taskbar breaks; moving the mouse to the bottom of my screen will no longer pull up the taskbar. This is *really* annoying as pressing the Windows key no longer brings up the taskbar.

Note that I am launching this through the *desktop*, not as a metro app. Internet Explorer does not exhibit this behavior, and restoring down fixes it. What's going on here?

Comment: I think its a bug at your side as it's working fine on my laptop.

Comment: Which channel/release of chrome?

Comment: Have you try to update your chrome?

Comment: @RalfTheiss The machine in question has since been nuked once, reinstalled with Windows 7, nuked again, and now scrapped for parts. I have not been able to reproduce the issue anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152241) its a bug. But there is a different version of Chrome than the latest one.

The latest version is 22.0.1229.94m while the bug issue is for the version 21.0.1180.89. Be sure you are up to date with the Chrome.

Comment: That bug is for full-screen and the question is about 'maximized' mode, so the correct issue is #373194 here code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373194  
and it is not resolved for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this was irritating me also.

Use the tab in the right corner of Chrome (that you would normally use to go to your chrome settings)

Then click the "Relaunch Chrome in Windows 8 mode" (it may be called "Relaunch from the desktop").

This worked for me.  Hope it helps

Comment: Arg, this launches in the start menu. Horrible.

Comment: Yes, the problem does not occur in windows 8 mode, but that mode has its problems too, and the question was specifically about 'desktop' mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep Chrome maximized, but not fullscreen. It leaves some unnecessary UI window elements at sides, but allows access to taskbar.

The problem is still reproducible on Chrome version 26.0.1410.43 m
I also suspect that it can have something in common with dual-monitor setup, because when yesterday I was working on single monitor I didn't observe this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I have version 39.0.2171.95 on Windows 8, and this issue still persists. I use chrome on the desktop maximized, and sometimes it ends up covering up the taskbar. When I updated to Windows 8.1 it worked fine, but I've gone back to Windows 8.

My fix is to switch to a different window, right click the taskbar -> properties -> task bar location on screen, change it to a different value (left), switch to chrome, then switch back and change the task bar location back to the original value (bottom).